# Convert this Matlab matrix with Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have this code in Matlab

```
[r,c] = find(abs(fh) <= 2 )
```

Which creates a 39342 x 2 matrix.

fh is a 19739 x 2 matrix.

I want to achieve the same in Python and with numpy I've come out with

```
rc = np.nonzero(np.abs(fh) <= 2)[0]
```

But this code produces only a row vector with 39342 columns.

The problem is that I want those 39342 as rows, and by doing this I also lose the 2nd column of the original fh array upon which the original find operates in Matlab.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `nonzero` produces a tuple that can be used to index `fh` diectly.  `argwhere` applies `transpose` to it, but that can't be used as an index.

Comment: Using [0] throws away the column indexing array, [1].  What do you want to use this duplicate for?

Comment: yes it was a mistake due to the wrong assumption I've made about fh

Comment: Did you try r,c = np.nonzero(....)`?  That should do the same unpacking that your MATLAB `[r,c]=...` does.

Comment: yes, I'm trying nonzero since I realized I'm actually interested only in r and not in c. So the code is now rc = np.nonzero(np.abs(fh) <= 2)[0]. Result is almost 100% good now because in Matlab I have [78, .... , 39455] and in Python I have [77, ..., 39454]. Python result is off by one... some index related issue maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is transpose the `numpy` matrix, notice the `where` returns the indices in reversed order then in matlab.

Matlab:

```
fh = rand(5,2)
% fh =
% 
%    0.39936   0.72931
%    0.45787   0.23656
%    0.30444   0.52994
%    0.40239   0.64400
%    0.89489   0.47090
[r,c] = find(abs(fh) <= 0.4 )
% r =
% 
%    1
%    3
%    2

% c =
% 
%    1
%    1
%    2
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np

fh = np.array([[0.39936   ,0.72931],
[0.45787   ,0.23656],
[0.30444   ,0.52994],
[0.40239   ,0.64400],
[0.89489   ,0.47090]])

res = np.where(np.abs(fh.T) <= 0.4)
print(res)
# (array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 2, 1]))
```

**EDIT**

To transform it to a list of np.arrays you can do:

```
res = np.array(list(map(np.array, np.where(np.abs(fh.T) <= 0.4))))
print(res.T)
print(res.T.shape)

# [[0 0]
#  [0 2]
#  [1 1]]
# (3, 2)
```

**EDIT**

As @hpaulj suggested in the comment, using `np.argwhere` solve it elegantly:

```
res = np.argwhere(np.abs(fh.T) <= 0.4)
print(res)
# [[0 0]
#  [0 2]
#  [1 1]]
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that res is of type tuple, in fact I can't do res.size on it. It would be great if I can convert it somehow to a vector, the same as you did with the np.array function

Comment: I'm trying but I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size' . Seems like res is still not considered array

Comment: @claw91 so instead of `list` just use `np.array` and then get the `shape` like my edit

Comment: `argwhere` does `transpose(res)` making a (n,2) array.

Comment: @hpaulj you are absolutely correct, I added it to my answer. Thanks for enlighten me

Comment: my bad, going through Matlab and Python different syntax is driving me crazy. fh is actually an array itself with 39342  values, and not a  39342 x 2 matrix as stated in my original post. With @hpaulj suggestion res is 39342 x 1 matrix but it's still different from the Matlab code in which res is a 39342 x 2 matrix